# Is the gradient of $\langle z, F(\cdot)\rangle$ Lipschitz continuous when the one of $F$ is?

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, operator-theory, vector-analysis, lipschitz-functions

This is my first topic here, please apologise if I am doing something wrong.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces with their duals $X^*$ and $Y^*$, respectively, and $F:X\to Y$ with the Frechet gradient Lipschitz continuous with constant $L$. Let $z\in Y^*$ with $\|z\|=1$ (can be also $\leq 1$ or equal to some given constant). What can be said about the Lipschitz continuity of the gradient of the function defined by $x \mapsto \langle z , F(x) \rangle$? One has 
$∇ \langle z, F(x) \rangle = z \circ ∇F(x)$, but from here I am lost and I need to show that $∇ \langle z, F(x) \rangle$ is Lipschitz continuous and to determine the corresponding Lipschitz constant.

Thank you all in advance for any hint or answer, which will be credited in my Master' Thesis.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I tried editing but I couldn't figure out the last two lines

Comment: $\nabla G(x_1) - \nabla G(x_2) = z \circ \bigl(\nabla F(x_1) - \nabla F(x_2)\bigr)$

Comment: thanks, I'll ty this

Comment: @DanielFischer: you mean that one can write
     
||∇G(x)−∇G(y)||=||z∘(∇F(x)−∇F(y))|| $\leq$ ||z|| ||∇F(x)−∇F(y)|| $\leq$ L||x-y||, so the answer were that the function is Lipschitz continuous with L as the constant?

Comment: Indeed. For general $z$, we get a Lipschitz constant of $\lVert z\rVert\cdot L$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I see, but how exactly should we define  z∘∇F(x), as $z:Y\rightarrow R$ and $\nabla F(x)\in L(X, Y)$?

Comment: $z \circ \nabla F(x) \colon h \mapsto z\bigl(\nabla F(x)(h)\bigr)$.

Comment: thanks, Daniel, this sounds good.